# byobu endlessly printing status lines to terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, tmux, byobu

I've started using byobu recently and found it very enjoyable, but this morning I must have accidentally hit some random control sequence and it went into a very strange state where it keeps echoing status lines to the terminal, hiding everything else. See the screen shot to see what I mean (my hostname and ip address have been cropped out of the screen shot).

Exiting byobu and restarting doesn't seem to help. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to stop it printing status lines like this? I've tried Google, but it's really hard to translate the problem into a set of search terms.

[screen shot of my terminal (hostname and ip address cropped out from right-hand side)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEzc0.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so weirdly leaving it for a few hours and then rejoining the byobu session was apparently enough for it to stop. Maybe it was just over-excited?